# Get Text Format of RichTextArea Value

Tags: vaadin

Is there any form to get the format of the text written in a RichTextArea?

For example, I want to get the font type, size, and so forth. I need those values to pass them to a PDF writer, so that the text of the PDF is in the same format than in the RichTextArea.

I am using iText and this is an example:

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

//The value of font should be the font of the text written in the RichTextArea
paragraph.add(new Chunk(text,font));

document.add(paragraph);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get format of the text written in RichTextArea you must to parse component value.

Value of the RichTextArea is html code, on example:

```html
<font face="Arial" size="6">Additional Text</font>
```

But it is complicated, so to get pdf from html you can use iText HTMLWorker.

See the link: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html

Comment: How can I parse the ComponentValue to a string?

Comment: you can use getValue() method on RichTextArea component

Comment: getValue() returns a normal text, not the HTML code

Comment: @VíctorGómez you are not right. Regular text will be result only if you don't use any style. Try to edit text, change font and size, then get the value.